# Python Geometric Sequence Sum

Tags: python

I would like to calculate the   sum of  the first   25 numbers in the sequence: 2, 4,   8,  16, 32....

Why am I receiving an output that says the sum is 50 when it should be higher?

```
 t = 2
    sum = 0
    for i in range (1, 26) :
        sum += t
    t *= 2
    print("i: ", i, "t: ", t, "sum: ", sum)
    i:  25 t:  4 sum:  50
```

Comment: You are just adding up the numbers, python is layout sensitive, your `t *= 2` needs to be indented. Note: using `sum` as a variable name hides pythons builtin in `sum()` function and is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a little typo, in the loop, your adding `t` to `sum`, when it should be `t**i`, and also, it's not good to name variables a replica of a existing keyword, that makes you unable to access that keyword.

So do (whole code):

```
t = 2
s = 0
for i in range (1, 26) :
    s += t
    t *= 2
print("i: ", i, "t: ", t, "sum: ", s)
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
t = 2
s = 0
for i in range (1, 26) :
    s += t**i
print("i: ", i, "t: ", t**i, "sum: ", s)
```

Comment: I think the OP's issue is that the `t *= 2` is incorrectly indented, though `t**i` would be another way of getting the right result. There is a simple calculation for the same result: `2**26-2`.

Comment: @AChampion That's right, i edited, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: You can't do both, either indent or replace with `t**i`.

Comment: @AChampion Sorry but can you please do the edit for me, because i have to leave from my computer...

Comment: @AChampion Thank you for editing mine, i am back to my computer, :-), 